# Is Big-Theta a more accurate description of worst case run time than Big-O?

Tags: asymptotics, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation, notation

Question I was asked: Does it make a difference if I say "The worst case run time is $O(n^2)$ vs the worst case run time is $\Theta(n^2)$?"

To me, the only difference is that when we say $O(n^2)$, the function may also be $O(n)$, we do not know. But when we say $\Theta(n^2)$, we know for a fact the function is $O(n^2)$ and $\Omega(n^2)$, because it is bounded by $c_1n^2\leq f(n)\leq c_2n^2$ (correct me if I am wrong).

Therefore, can we not say that $\Theta(n^2)$ gives us a more accurate (or at least equal) sense of worst-case run time than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: In your last sentence, did you really mean O(n), not O(n^2)?  O(n) is incompatible with Theta(n^2) (unlike vice versa), so no you *can't* say that.  But that sentence construction in English is saying you think we can say that.

Comment: Keep in mind that not all algorithms can have "Theta" complexity. There are algorithms that vary in complexity. Those can only be described with Big-O complexity. In that case to have a better understanding on the performance you want to define a statistical distribution of the inputs and then compute the average complexity. That complexity can be described in "theta" terms... unfortunately computing the average complexity is often really difficult/time consuming or even intractable.

Comment: One minor thing that may help.  When we say that something $O(n^2)$ or $\Theta(n^2)$ we typically have to prove it.  Sometimes the proof for $\Theta$ is natural, sometimes its harder.  And often the O is all we really need for our proofs, so we are often lazy in that regard.

Comment: I agree with @Peter Cordes.  Perhaps that point should be responded to or even an edit made?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes i meant n^2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  Your understanding is correct on all points!

Answer (score 8):

O(f(n)) is also used when there is no simple function that your runtime is close to. For example: Find the smallest prime factor of n by trial division, finishing when a factor is found: There are O(n^1/2) tests if you divide by all integers up to the square root of n. But for even n there is only one test, and similar if n has any small factor.

So you can’t give any reasonable Theta unless you say f(n) = Theta(f(n)) which is true but pointless.

There is also the possibility that I can *prove* that a function is for example $O(n^2)$. I may suspect it is actually smaller, it may actually be $O(n)$ but I cannot prove it. Obviously in that situation I can also not prove that it is $\Theta(n^2)$ - because it isn't true.

Comment: This example is a bit contrived because you used `n` as the value of the input, as opposed to the length of the input. If you used `n` as the length of the input, then there would be many different values of input for the same `n`, and typically one of them will achieve the worst-case.

Comment: Using `n` as the input isn't contrived. `O` is not a computer science concept and so length doesn't pertain to it in general.

Comment: For moderately sized numbers, giving the runtime or number of divisions relative to the number n instead of the size of the number n is more useful. And of course who says we always want to know the worst case? The average case is also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You answer yourself by saying that $\Theta$ is the conjunction of $O$ and $\Omega$. So yes of course, $\Theta$ is more informative than $O$ alone.

Make sure anyway that you don't confuse the asymptotic behavior of the algorithm complexity, and that of its worst-case complexity.

E.g. the running-time of QuickSort is $O(n^2)$ and $\Omega(n\log n)$, while its worst-case running-time is $\Theta(n^2)$.